# Treeview binding data in C

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writting a Win32 aplication that view PE file header. I use Treeview to display structure of PE file. When I click item in treeview, a Listview will display it data.

My problem is I only add title to treeview, so when I click item, I don't know what it is (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER, PIMAGE_NT_HEADER,.., PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[0], PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[1],..).

So how can I click an item and I get data that associate with clicked item?

```
HTREEITEM AddTreeViewItem(HTREEITEM Parent, char title[]) {
    tvInsert.hParent = Parent;
    tvInsert.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
    tvInsert.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
    tvInsert.item.pszText = title;
    return (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tvInsert);
}
```

I follow this tutorial, bui I want to make my own app with UI https://pastebin.com/LTN6VjJE

Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Set `tvInsert.item.lParam` to point to some data?

Comment: But how do I get it out to use?

Comment: Thank you! I set item.mask is TVIF_TEXT so every thing else is invalid! Problem solve! :3